# Javascript Checkbox Array with multiple selection results

Tags: javascript, arrays, select, checkbox

I have a javascript array code my co-worker built. I've fixed it up so depending on the checkbox you select it will go to a designated page (zero.html. zeroone.html etc). What I want to accomplish now is to make it so when you select multiple checkboxes, it will go to another page based on the checkboxes selected.

Here is our code:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!-- Activate Cloaking Device -->

// Set in dataBase() function - used as array index.
var recnum="";
// Used to initialize arrays.
function initArray()
    {
this.length = initArray.arguments.length;
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
    { this[i] = initArray.arguments[i]; }
}
// Creating the arrays
var rcrd = new initArray();
var address = new initArray();
address[0] = "zero.html";
address[1] = "one.html";
address[2] = "two.html";
address[0,1] = "zeroone.html";
address[0,2] = "zerotwo.html";
address[1,2] = "onetwo.html";
address[0,1,2] = "zeroonetwo.html";

// Called by onClick for each checkbox button - determines & displays url in full window
function dataBase(leapto)
{
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
    if (leapto.buttons[i].checked)
        { recnum = leapto.buttons[i].value; }
    }
if ( (rcrd[recnum] !=null) && (rcrd[recnum] != "") )
    { document.leapto.display.value = rcrd[recnum]+"\r\n\r\n"+address[recnum]; }
}
// Called by Search Now button - Loads preselected page.

function leapTo()
{
if ( (address[recnum] !=null) && (address[recnum] != "") && (recnum != "") )
window.location= address[recnum];
else 
    alert("\nYou must make a selection first.");
}
// Deactivate Cloaking
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="leapto">
<input type="checkbox" name="buttons" value="0" onclick="dataBase(this.form)" /> Zero<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="buttons" value="1" onclick="dataBase(this.form)" /> One<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="buttons" value="2" onclick="dataBase(this.form)" /> Two<br />
<input type="button" class="classname" width="400" height="50" border="0" value="Search Now" onclick="leapTo()" /></form>
<script>
function myFunction(){var x;if (name!=null)  {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;}}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: BTW, we haven't needed <!-- --> script cloaking since about 1997.

Comment: Old habit, mostly for my notes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the help, after going through the items here I got a friend who knows jquery pretty well and got it working with the ideas from both of you guys.

Here is my code:
http://cdpn.io/zLuDC

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking how to make it more simple.

**HTML**

```
<div id="our-checkboxes">
     <input type="checkbox" value="zero"/>
     <input type="checkbox" value="one"/>
     <input type="checkbox" value="two"/>
     <input type="button" value="Click me to go to page" id="btn-to-click" />
</div>
```

ok so that is HTML, now I would write Javascript using jQuery library

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-to-click').click(function(){
       var _page = "";
       if($('#our-checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 0)
       {
           alert('you need to select at least one!');
           return false;
       }
       $('#our-checkboxes input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
          _page += $(this).val();
       });
       _page += ".html";
       alert('this is your page');
    });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Senad. Unfortunately my javascript knowledge is very low on the totem pole. Could you elaborate more? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can write it in this way, using JQuery:

```
var address = [["1","one.html"],["2","two.html"],["1-2","otherpage.php"]];

var toRespondToEventAfterTheSelection = function(){
  var selection = '';
  $("#parentOfInputs input:checked").each(function(i,e){
    if (selection != '') selection += "-";
    selection += $(e).val();
  });
  if (selection != ''){
    var page = '';
    for (dir in address) {
      if (address[dir][0] == selection){
        page = address[dir][1];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (page != '') document.location = page;
  }
});
```

Another alternative solution is, after getting the string with the selection, you can create a file in the server that respond to this string sending the user to the corresponding page of showing an error.

Comment: Thanks Moises, unfortunately we don't have access to the server and PHP isn't enabled (why we're not sure).

Comment: In that case, this Javascript can be a solution. You can adapt easily the values, and the number, of the checkboxes without changing the counters.